# Passing collection data from partial view to controller

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller, partial-views, icollection

I'm need to pass dynamically created data from a partial view to the controller on submit from the main form.

Here's the Action that returns the partial view:

```
[HttpGet]
public virtual PartialViewResult AddItem()
{
    var item = new QuotedItem();
    ViewBag.StockID = new SelectList(db.StockItems.OrderBy(s => s.Name), "StockID", "Name");
    return PartialView("EditorTemplates/QuotedItem", item);
}
```

Here's the EditorTemplate for QuotedItem:

```
@model StockSystem.Models.QuotedItem

<div id="itemRow">

    <span>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StockID, null)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StockID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </span>
    <span>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </span>
    <span>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Quantity)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Quantity, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </span>

    <a href="#" class="deleteSmall"></a>

</div>
```

Here's the View:

```
@model StockSystem.Models.Quote

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>New Quote for @ViewBag.Customer</h2>

<hr />
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.Hidden("CustomerID", (object)ViewBag.CustomerID)

    <div class="addItem">
        @Ajax.ActionLink(" ", "AddItem",
        new AjaxOptions
        {
            UpdateTargetId = "editorRows",
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter,
            HttpMethod = "GET"
        })
    </div>

    <div id="editorRows">
        @Html.EditorFor(q => q.QuotedItems)
    </div>

    <p></p>

    <div>
        <input class="add" type="submit" value="" />
        <a class="back" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Quotes", new { id = ViewBag.CustomerID })"></a>
    </div>
}
```

Here's the Create Action:

```
 public ActionResult Create(int id)
 {
     var customer = db.Customers.Find(id);
     ViewBag.CustomerID = id;
     ViewBag.Customer = customer.CustomerName;
     var quote = new Quote() { QuotedItems = new List<QuotedItem>() };
     return View(quote);
 }
```

Here's the EF model for QuotedItem:

```
public partial class QuotedItem
{
    public int QuotedItemID { get; set; }
    public int QuoteID { get; set; }
    public int StockID { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public virtual Quote Quote { get; set; }
    public virtual StockItem StockItem { get; set; }
}
```

And Quote:

```
public partial class Quote
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Quote()
    {
        this.QuotedItems = new HashSet<QuotedItem>();
    }

    public int QuoteID { get; set; }
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime QuoteDate { get; set; }
    public string QuoteRef { get; set; }

    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<QuotedItem> QuotedItems { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

I can add items to the page but they are not added to the quote on submit.

```
 [HttpPost]
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
 public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "QuoteID,CustomerID,UserID,QuoteDate,QuoteRef,QuotedItems")] Quote quote) //, List<QuotedItem> items
 {
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
         //quote.QuotedItems is empty, how do I bind this data and save to database?         
         db.Quotes.Add(quote);
         db.SaveChanges();
         return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = quote.CustomerID });
     }

     return View(quote);
 }
```

The collection is not being sent to the controller. How is this done?

Thanks

Edit: I was thinking about trying this:

```
 [HttpPost]
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
 public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "QuoteID,CustomerID,UserID,QuoteDate,QuoteRef,QuotedItems")] Quote quote, List<QuotedItem> items)
 {
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
         quote.QuotedItems = items;
         db.Quotes.Add(quote);
         db.SaveChanges();
         return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = quote.CustomerID });
     }

     return View(quote);
 }
```

But I thought there must be a better way. If I were try this approach I'm still not entirely sure how to send this to the controller, I assume as a parameter in Html.BeginForm()? I'm fairly new to MVC and still getting to grips with the conventions.

Answer (score 0):

By using the Bind attribute in your method signature, you are preventing the `QuotedItems` property from being posted to the controller action.

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "QuoteID,CustomerID,UserID,QuoteDate,QuoteRef")] Quote quote)
```

Adding the `QuotedItems` property name to the include list should solve this:

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "QuoteID,CustomerID,UserID,QuoteDate,QuoteRef,QuotedItems")] Quote quote)
```

**EDIT**

Without seeing your QuotedItem editor template, it's hard to say for sure, but it sounds like your issue might be that each item added to your list doesn't have a unique id set on the elements that make up that item. Without this, the model binder will struggle to work out which element belongs to which object in the collection.

Take a look at these two articles and see if they help:

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

https://www.mattlunn.me.uk/blog/2014/08/how-to-dynamically-via-ajax-add-new-items-to-a-bound-list-model-in-asp-mvc-net/

**Edit 2**

Each element in your template should be given a unique ID, an index is a good way to do this, so are item GUIDs (if you have them); but as long as each element ID is unique to that item it should work.

```
@model StockSystem.Models.QuotedItem

<div id="itemRow">
<span>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StockID, null)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StockID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</span>
<span>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = $"[{YOURINDEX}].Price" } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</span>
<span>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Quantity, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = $"[{YOURINDEX}].Quantity" } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Quantity, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</span>

<a href="#" class="deleteSmall"></a>
```

In the code above the `[YOURINDEX]` value would need to be incremented for each new item added to the collection.

How you implement and increment that index is up to you, but I would suggest reading the two articles I linked to previously to get an understanding of why this is necessary.

Comment: I've already tried that. The collection still ends up being empty.

Comment: are you initialising the `QuoteItems` collection in the HttpGet Create action?

Comment: Guy - I have edited my question to show the Create Action.

Comment: I have also edited the question to include models for `Quote` and `QuotedItem` I am using Entity Framework to produce these.

Comment: I have edited the question to also include the Editor Template.

Comment: The html attributes for id and name are being overwritten for some reason. Would it be worth using the 3rd party Html helper `Html.BeginCollectionItem` for this?